# MS Access: find rows with different fields in two tables

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access:

I am trying to compare two tables with:

```
- TABLE1.docnumb1 = TABLE2.docnumb2
- looking for: TABLE1.sum <> TABLE2.sum2
```

But query retrieves an error: syntax error in from clause (or when creating left join I get an error that JOIN isn't supported):

```
SELECT docnumb1, sum 
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON docnumb1 = docnumb2;
```

How do I query the rows with different values?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use left join

```
SELECT docnumb1, sum 
FROM Table1 a
left JOIN Table2 b ON a.docnumb1 = b.docnumb2 and a.value=b.value
where b.docnumb2 is null
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ON a.docnumb1 = b.docnumb2` just for complete clarity?

Answer (score 0):

looking to your sample (image)
you could compare the subquery for sum

```
    select  t1.rownumb, t1.sum1 -t2.sum2 
    from  (
    SELECT rownumb, sum(value)  sum1 
    FROM Table1 
    group by rownumb
    ) t1 
    INNER JOIN 
     (
    SELECT rownumb, sum(value)  sum2 
    FROM Table2 
    group by rownumb
    ) t2 ON t1.rownumb = t2.rownumb and  (t1.sum1 -t2.sum2 ) <> 0
```